# Fixed part of the induced representation

Tags: representation-theory, arithmetic, sheaf-theory, etale-cohomology, galois-representations

Suppose the topological groups $h, G$ satisfy that $H < G$ and that $[G \colon H] < \infty$. Let $V$ be a $K$-vector space on which $H$ acts continuously. Then we consider the induced $G$-representation $W \colon= {\Bbb Z}[G] \otimes_{{\Bbb Z}[H]} V$.

Q. How can I *explicitly* understand the equality $W^{H} = \underset{[G \colon H]}{\oplus} V^{H}$?

What if $[G \colon H] = 2$?

Comment: Does $W^H$ mean the $H$-invariant vectors? This seems to follow directly from Mackey decomposition (which is completely explicit)

Comment: Yes. H-invariant vectors. What is Mackey decomposition?